# Efficient distance matrix computation in Java/Scala, bsxfun for java/scala

Tags: java, scala, matrix, distance, bsxfun

I need computing distance matrix for a given vector, something which in octave/matlab is very quick with bsxfun(@minus,x',x).

Is there some function in Java/Scala which would compute distance matrix in Java/Scala as fast as in Octave/Matlab?

Comment: Did you check this library?: https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Linear-Algebra-Cheat-Sheet

Comment: yes, that one I use at the moment, also asked David Hall (author of this lib), and there is no such functionality built-in. I just found this in apache mahout, just testing how fast is it:

Comment: def sqDist(mxX: Matrix): Matrix = {

    val s = mxX ^ 2 rowSums

    (mxX %*% mxX.t) := { (r, c, x) ⇒ s(r) + s(c) - 2 * x}
  }

Comment: there is actually a function in mahout called sq_dist(x), and it is 4-5 times slower than sq_dist from gpml library, which uses bsxfun, tested on x=[1:4000]' vector

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I guess it the time to write your own and maybe even contribute ;)

Comment: Never quite sure why people think that dedicated library functions in Octave, Matlab, and Mathematica would be in a standard programming language. If they were it would essentially make those products redundant!

Answer (score 0):

Best solution I came up with so far, still 3 times slower than sq_dist function from gpml package:

https://github.com/danielkorzekwa/bayes-scala-gp/blob/master/src/main/scala/dk/gp/math/sqDist.scala

https://github.com/danielkorzekwa/bayes-scala-gp/blob/master/src/test/scala/dk/gp/math/sqDistTest.scala